# Preserve dropdown hover when circular button and dropdown are separated by a gap

Tags: html, css

The main issue is caused by a button being circular. But I really want a circular button, which is leading to hovering problems!
All I want is to have a circular `<a>` button that when hovered-over will reveal another element below it, like a div or another a tag. These two elements are separated by a gap.

Then I should be able to move my mouse down and hover over the revealed element and click on it or whatever. But of course if you unhover the original `<a>` then the other element will disappear, especially since there is a gap between the two elements. What is the best way to make it so that I can move my mouse from element 1 to element 2 without element 2 vanishing during mouse travel?

Ideally this shouldn't require JS.

I've created a basic setup for this so far to get started:

```css
body {
  padding: 30px;
  height: 100vh;
}

#myBtn {
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#hoverInfo {
  display: none;
  margin-top: 40px;
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}

#myBtn:hover + #hoverInfo, #hoverInfo:hover {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a id="myBtn" href="/">
  button
</a>

<a id="hoverInfo" href="/">hover info</a>
```

Here's an explanation of an old solution attempt of mine:

My first solution to stop element 2 from vanishing upon downward movement of the mouse was to put an invisible hoverable element between elem 1 and 2 which would keep elem 2 active while the mouse moves down to it. And this would work great, IF all elements were rectangular. But my elem 1 is circular!

This means that there is literally one single pixel of contact between the middle hover buffer element and elem 1 because there are those circular "corner" gaps between elem 1 and the invisible middle element. So whenever you move your mouse down, you are still going to miss that middle hover element 99% of the time.

And you can't put it behind elem 1 either to fill in those circular "corners" because the circular element has a bounding box that you can only see in inspect element and this bbox prevents you from filling up those "corners" with an area that actually interacts with the mouse, therefore making this solution useless. It's quite confusing in my explanation but try it out if you manage to implement this "solution".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this easily using a pseudo element that will make the hoverable area bigger and that you activate only on hover:

```css
body {
  padding: 30px;
  height: 100vh;
}

#myBtn {
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position:relative;
}
#myBtn:before {
   content:"";
   display:none;
   position:absolute;
   top:90%;
   left:0;
   right:0;
   height:28px;
}

#hoverInfo {
  display: none;
  margin-top: 40px;
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}

#myBtn:hover::before {
  display:block;
  background:rgba(0,0,255,0.2); /* to illustrate */
}
#myBtn:hover + #hoverInfo, #hoverInfo:hover {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a id="myBtn" href="/">
  button
</a>

<a id="hoverInfo" href="/">hover info</a>
```

Comment: Works great, thanks! I believe this is the best solution. Only issue is that the ::before area is a part of the button itself and so you can click on it as a link. It's a small price to pay for the simplicity.

Answer (score 2):

The first solution to come to mind is wrapping the circular button into a parent div, which will be the div that will activate the hover effect. This way, you can add padding-bottom to imitate the gap look while still making the "gap area" trigger the hover effect. In the snippet below, I made the wrapper div have a red background so you can see how it works. If you remove the red background, it should function as intended.

https://codepen.io/xenvi/pen/yLONOEa

```css
body {
  padding: 30px;
  height: 100vh;
}

.buttonWrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  background: red;
}

#myBtn {
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#hoverInfo {
  display: none;
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}

.buttonWrapper:hover+#hoverInfo,
#hoverInfo:hover {
  display: block;
}

.buttonWrapper:hover {
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttonWrapper">
  <a id="myBtn" href="/">
  button
  </a>
</div>

<a id="hoverInfo" href="/">hover info</a>
```

Comment: Thank you. There is still one big problem with this implementation though: the red area is always active, even when I am not hovering over anything at all. This effectively means that (when the red area is invisible) the button is just basically bigger but half of it being invisible. Would it be possible for the red area to only be active when the button is hovered over, just like the original element that I wanted to appear? 

I can't just set the red area to display:none because then the effect cascades down to every single element. (Although maybe there is a way around it?)

Comment: Instead of setting the display attribute of the red area, what if you changed the size so that it was no longer bigger than the button?

Comment: Interesting point Keara, I fiddled with the code a bit more so that the red area begins as margin instead of padding (so not hoverable), but on button hover, switches the margin to padding so it is hoverable. This effect only lasts when hovering the button though, not when hovering the info box. Could use a bit more fiddling with if you want to make it so the red area stays hoverable even when mousing over the info.

Comment: I tried keeping the size at zero and then made to the size of the button on hover but this was causing serious positioning problems therefore creating another problem to solve and another and another. It was all just getting extremely complicated too fast. I think the limitations of CSS simply being cascading in nature is the issue here as I'm trying to control everything. I instead went with Temani's answer which is far more simple and works great, with the only tiny exception that the middle buffer area is created with ::before, therefore part of the button itself on hover. A small price.